# show hide multiple columns in jquery datatable.net

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there any convenient way to show/hide table columns in jquery datatable plugin?
I am using http://datatables.net/api to create a grid of boxes. with fixed header and fixed column. Which is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
             //var selectedElementId = '{!selectedElementId}';
            var oTable = $('#masterGridTable').dataTable( {
                "sScrollY": "255px",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "150%",
                "bScrollCollapse": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {

                }
            } );
            new FixedColumns( oTable );
        } );
```

following is the screen shot for this.
[image]

Now in the grid there are 15 minutes blocks starting from 8:15AM to 4:15PM
Requirement is to make a filter of Morning /Afternoon so that selecting morning hides all blocks from 12:00Pm to 4:15Pm and AFternoon hides morning entries. (8:15 AM to 12:00PM)

I tried using fnSetColumnVis function to show hide columns inside a loop.
Code :

```
function toggleShift(th){
        var selectedShift=$(th).val();
        var oTable = $('#masterGridTable').dataTable();
        if(selectedShift =='Full Day'){
            var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }else if(selectedShift =='Morning'){
            $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner table.dataTable tr:nth-child(2) .PM').each(function(){
                var indexV = $(this).index();
                oTable.fnSetColumnVis( indexV , false );
            });
        }else if(selectedShift =='Afternoon'){
            $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner table.dataTable tr:nth-child(2) .AM').each(function(){
                var indexV = $(this).index();
                oTable.fnSetColumnVis( indexV , false );
            });
        }
```

this funcion calls onchange event of drop down on top right (beside today text in image)
This works (not properly) 
1.  Hides wrong columns
2.  Its super slow :(
Any idea how to do that properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i did.
Which is working fine.
here what i am doing is that i am calling toggleShift() method on onchangeEvent of the list. inside that i make server side call. and on completion of that i am calling refresh table method which is just recreating the instance of the table.

```
function refreshTable(){
             var oTable = $('#masterGridTable').dataTable( {
                "sScrollY": "255px",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "150%",
                "bScrollCollapse": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {

                }
            } );
            new FixedColumns( oTable );
            $('#busyMsgDiv').hide();
        }
        function toggleShift(th){
            $('#busyMsgDiv').show();
            var selectedShiftVal = $(th).val() ;
            console.log(selectedShiftVal);
            changeShift1();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

yeap, you can do it like this:

First take `var oTable` out of the document.ready function, so that you have a reference to your table globally after you initialize it.

Then use:

```
var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true ); //This creates a toggle effect

//or
oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol,false);//hide
oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol,true);//show
```

Where iCol is the number of the column you want to hide.

Enjoy

More info here http://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Comment: thanks for the reply, but The problem is that There are more then 160 columns in the table, and need to hide half columns at a time, The code works, but it is very very slow.

Comment: Well, that fix my problem